# SQL counting and grouping with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

On my postgresql db I have a score table with the columns user_id, item_id, succeeded (bool) and created_at.

I want to count the number of succeeded items for each user and each item (where succeeded = 't'). But I only want to count succeeded item occurred after the last failure.

I try the following code without success.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), item_id
FROM score
WHERE score.succeeded = 't' AND user_id = XX 
GROUP BY score.item_id 
HAVING MAX(score.created_at) > score.created_at AND score.succeeded = 'f'
```

**exemple**

data:

```
user_id | item_id | succeeded | created_at
------------------------------------------
12      | 1       | true      | 2016-04-01
12      | 1       | false     | 2016-04-02
12      | 1       | true      | 2016-04-03

12      | 2       | true      | 2016-04-01
12      | 2       | true      | 2016-04-02
12      | 2       | true      | 2016-04-03

12      | 3       | true      | 2016-04-01
12      | 3       | true      | 2016-04-02
12      | 3       | false     | 2016-04-03
```

Excepted result (for user 12):

```
item_id | succeeded_count
-------------------------
1       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 0
```

Comment: Can you add sample table data, and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `NOT EXISTS` condition. It will make sure only true rows having no later false row are counted.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), s1.item_id
FROM score s1
WHERE score.succeeded = 't'
  AND s1.user_id = XX
  AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from score s2
                  where s2.user_id = s1.user_id
                    and s2.item_id = s1.item_id
                    and s2.succeeded = 'f'
                    and s2.created_at > s1.created_at)
GROUP BY s1.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be filtering the rows in the `where` clause.  Assuming that `succeeded` only takes the values of `'f'`  or `'t'`:

```
select s.item_id, count(*)
from score s
where s.created_at > (select max(s2.created_at)
                      from score s2
                      where s2.item_id = s.item_id and s2.succeeded = 'f'
                     )
group by s.item_id;
```

Note:  This will filter out values of `0`.  You can get all of them by using `join` instead:

```
select s.item_id, count(s2.item_id)
from scores s left join
     (select item_id, max(created_at) maxca
      from scores
      where succeeded = 'f'
      group by item_id
     ) ss
     on s.item_id = ss.item_id and s.created_at >= ss.maxca
group by item_id;
```

If `succeeded` can take on values other than `'f'`, then you can add a `where` clause to the outer query or use conditional aggregation.